# Too broad question: Shortcodes on my own website (not wordpress)

Tags: discussion

Why has the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919290/use-shortcodes-on-my-own-website-not-wordpress been put on hold?

As far as I can see, it's a perfectly legitimate question, with at least one quick answer:

```
$shortcodes = Array(
    'button' => '<button>{content}</button>',
    'input' => '<input type="text" value="{content}" />'
);

$text = preg_replace_callback('(\[([a-z]+?)\](.+?)\[\\\1\]', function ($matches) {
    if ($shortcodes[$matches[1]]) {
        return str_replace('{content}', $matches[2], $shortcodes[$matches[1]]);
    } else {
        return $matches[0];
    }
}, $text);
```

What should be done in cases like this?

Comment: That is **one** way to do it. There are virtually infinite ways of doing this - server and client side. The on hold reason is accurate - "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format".

Comment: @Oded OK, but what do you say to the user in cases like this?

Comment: I tell them to read the close notice that is under the question (under the comments, actually). It tells them the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is put on hold because the question is so open ended that it can literally receive thousands of answers and each would be equally valid.

The asker should make an attempt him(her)self, see where (s)he got stuck and then ask a question about the specific problem. There won't be as much room for different answers and (s)he will get something that can definitely be worked with.

Comment: OK. However, the question is a really useful one, actually.